# VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry

Tags: vlc, systemd, ubuntu-mate

When this is run

```
#!/bin/bash 
#
# located in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
# Created 4/2/19
exec 2> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test_err.txt

if [ "${1}" = "pre" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want before suspend here
  echo "we are suspending $(date +%I:%M:%S_%D)." 
elif [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resume here
   echo "and we are back from being suspended $(date +%I:%M:%S_%D)" 
  # gxmessage works IF xhost + is run first.
  gxmessage -timeout 5 -fg red -display :0 'Back from being suspended.'
  cvlc /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Relax_6_Seconds.mp3
fi
```

I get

```
VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry.
If you need to use real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports
you can use /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and
cannot be run by non-trusted users first).
```

I am not sure of the correct way of Set-UID root.

Comment: You could probably use the simple `aplay` instead of loading the whole `cvlc` app.

Comment: If `ls -l /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper` begins with `-rws`, then it IS SetUID to the owner of the file.

Comment: ls -l /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10232 Oct  6 20:20 /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper
@waltinator

Comment: aplay is confusing to say the least. How do I find what channel I need. Could not find an example of how to play an mp3. @Jos

Comment: aplay -c 1 -t wav -r 44100 -f Relax_6_Seconds.wav
aplay: main:604: wrong extended format 'Relax_6_Seconds.wav'

Comment: I setUID for  /usr/bin/vlc-wrapper. Now when I run script it says Cannot determine unprivileged user for VLC! @waltinator